# .NET core support for SqlFileStream or any alternative way to get a filestream out of SQL Server using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, filestream, filetable

I noticed `SqlFileStream` is not supported in .NET Core. But then read it might be available in 3.0? I have some sample code in .NET classic.

Basically I am trying to get the data somehow from a SQL command in C# to a filestream that I can copy to another folder location.

Comment: The best way is use a SQLDataAdapter and fill a DataTable (dt) with the results of a query.  Then you can use the dt.WriteXml(filename) to save the query to an xml file.  If you need a stream then create a memory stream and write the xml to the memory stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two APIs for Filestream.  There's a Win32 handle-based API, which isn't available in .NET Core, and the ordinary TSQL API, which is.  A Filestream file appears to the TSQL API as varbinary(max) column, and can be accessed like any other varbinary(max) column.

In particular you can use [SqlClient Streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support) for streaming access to varbinary(max) data in SQL Server, whether it's stored in the file system (FileStream/FileTable), or inside your SQL Server database files.  In fact the sample on that doc page shows you how to stream a varbinary(max) column into a local file.